# How to notify an event without props from descendant to ancestor component

Tags: reactjs

I've a component (`<Grid>`) with `n` nested components

```
<Grid>
    <Header>
        <Toolbar>
           ...
        </Toolbar>
        <Filters>
            <Form>
               ...
            </Form>
        </Filters>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Datazone>
            ...
        </Datazone>
        <Summary>
            ...
        </Summary>
    </Body>
    <Footer>
        ...
    </Footer>
</Grid>
```

I need to create a component (`<MagicButton>`) that can be placed everywhere into the `<Grid>` tree, wherever it is placed along the tree, when it's pressed it should do something and then "notify" an event to the `<Grid>` component.
prerequisite: *I don't want to use props drilling at all*, so I've thought of this solution:
To wrap the `<Grid>` in a context and pass a function that can notify/update the `<Grid>` in the context value. This function is "tirggered" from a `<MagicButton>` component that use the context `useContext`

is this approch correct?
If yes, is it possible to provide the `<MagicButton>` component through/by the context instead of "import" then `<MagicButton>` component into a grid's child component `<Toolbar>` e.g.
If not, is there another approch to notify to an anchestor component (without no props drilling obviously)

```
<GridPersistenceStateContext.Provider value={NotificationFunction}>
    <Grid>
        <Header>
            <Toolbar>
            <MagicButton />
            </Toolbar>
            <Filters>
                <Form>
                ...
                </Form>
            </Filters>
        </Header>
        <Body>
            <Datazone>
                ...
            </Datazone>
            <Summary>
                <MagicButton />
            </Summary>
        </Body>
        <Footer>
            <MagicButton />
        </Footer>
    </Grid>
<GridPersistenceStateContext.Provider />
```

Does the "custom event" approch reppresent a viable alternative?
can "custom events" cause problems to the normal react lifecicle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Context provides a way to share values like these between components without having to explicitly pass a prop through every level of the tree. It's the correct approach.
2. It's possible to provide the `<MagicButton>` component through the context instead of `import` the `<MagicButton>` component everywhere. we can use [`SomeContext.Consumer`](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext#consumer),  an older way to read context. So that we can get the `MagicButton` component and render it.

E.g.

`MagicButton.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export const MagicButton = (props: any) => <button {...props}>magic button</button>;
```

`context.ts`:

```
import React from 'react';

export const GridPersistenceStateContext = React.createContext<{
    notify: (from: string) => void;
    MagicButton: (props: any) => JSX.Element;
}>(null!);
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { GridPersistenceStateContext } from './context';
import { MagicButton } from './MagicButton';

const Toolbar = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) => <div>{children}</div>;

export default function App() {
    const notificationFunction = (from: string) => {
        console.log('notified from: ', from);
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <GridPersistenceStateContext.Provider value={{ notify: notificationFunction, MagicButton }}>
                <div className="Header">
                    <Toolbar>
                        Toolbar:
                        <GridPersistenceStateContext.Consumer>
                            {({ MagicButton, notify }) => (
                                <MagicButton
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        notify('toolbar');
                                    }}
                                />
                            )}
                        </GridPersistenceStateContext.Consumer>
                    </Toolbar>
                </div>

                <div className="Body">
                    <div className="Summary">
                        Summary:
                        <GridPersistenceStateContext.Consumer>
                            {({ notify, MagicButton }) => (
                                <MagicButton
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        notify('summary');
                                    }}
                                />
                            )}
                        </GridPersistenceStateContext.Consumer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </GridPersistenceStateContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76727065-y69xy9)